# Mysql Data truncated for column error when modify a column definition

Tags: mysql

I have a table with the following column definition

```
 `numericValue1` double GENERATED ALWAYS AS ((case when (json_type(json_extract(`object`,'$.numericValue1')) = 'NULL')) then NULL else json_unquote(json_extract(`object`,'$.numericValue1')) end)) VIRTUAL;
```

Now I am trying to run the following script to change the column definition

```
ALTER TABLE `MyTable`
MODIFY `numericValue1` double GENERATED ALWAYS AS ((case when (json_type(json_extract(`object`,'$.numericValue1')) = 'NULL') OR (json_type(json_extract(`object`,'$.numericValue1')) = 'STRING') then NULL else json_unquote(json_extract(`object`,'$.numericValue1')) end)) VIRTUAL;
```

I then get an error

```
Data truncated for column 'numericValue1' at row 2
```

Any ideas? How can I by pass this error?

Comment: Does this column is used in some index?

Answer (score 0):

> ```
> CREATE TABLE `MyTable`(
> `object` JSON,
> `numericValue1` double GENERATED ALWAYS AS (case when (json_type(json_extract(`object`,'$.numericValue1')) = 'NULL') 
>                                                  then NULL 
>                                                  else json_unquote(json_extract(`object`,'$.numericValue1')) 
>                                                  end) VIRTUAL
> );
> ```

> ```
> INSERT INTO `MyTable` (`object`) VALUES 
> ('{"id":1,"numericValue1":123.456}'),
> ('{"id":2,"numericValue1":null}');
> ```

> ```
> INSERT INTO `MyTable` (`object`) VALUES 
> ('{"id":1,"numericValue1":"asdf"}');
> ```
>
> ```
> Data truncated for column 'numericValue1' at row 1
> ```

> ```
> SELECT * FROM `MyTable`;
> ```
>
> ```
> object                              | numericValue1
> :---------------------------------- | ------------:
> {"id": 1, "numericValue1": 123.456} |       123.456
> {"id": 2, "numericValue1": null}    |          null
> ```

> ```
> ALTER TABLE `MyTable`
> MODIFY `numericValue1` double GENERATED ALWAYS AS ((case when (json_type(json_extract(`object`,'$.numericValue1')) = 'NULL') OR (json_type(json_extract(`object`,'$.numericValue1')) = 'STRING') 
>                                                          then NULL 
>                                                          else json_unquote(json_extract(`object`,'$.numericValue1')) 
>                                                          end)) VIRTUAL;
> ```

> ```
> INSERT INTO `MyTable` (`object`) VALUES 
> ('{"id":1,"numericValue1":"asdf"}');
> ```

> ```
> SELECT * FROM `MyTable`;
> ```
>
> ```
> object                              | numericValue1
> :---------------------------------- | ------------:
> {"id": 1, "numericValue1": 123.456} |       123.456
> {"id": 2, "numericValue1": null}    |          null
> {"id": 1, "numericValue1": "asdf"}  |          null
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=19cbaf6661019cab343accab42380909)*

As you can see only when generated value does not match the datatype then shown error message is produced.